# No puedo guardar registros desde formulario con php en base de datos mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, vscode

Estoy realizando una página web de venta de entradas para eventos, tiene login, registro de usuarios hasta ahí funciona bien. Puedo crear Usuarios y loguearme con ellos pero al momento de crear un evento con un formulario, lleno el formulario apreto submit y se reinicia el formulario pero no me crea el registro en la base de datos. Lo extraño es que no me genera ningún error, alguien podría echarme un cable adjunto el código del formulario y el php

**Formulario: formulario_eventos.php**

```php
<?php

session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once '../config/conexionBD.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['idUser'])) {
    header('Location: ../../index.php');
} elseif (isset($_SESSION['idUser'])) {
    
    $idUser = $_SESSION['idUser'];
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE idOrg = $idUser";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
    if (!$resultado) {
        print_r(mysqli_error($conexion));
    }
} else {
    echo "ERROR EN EL SISTEMA";
}



?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Formulario Eventos | TaquillaNET</title>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="../../assets/apple-touch-icon.png" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="../../assets/favicon-32x32.png" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="../../assets/favicon-16x16.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="../../assets/site.webmanifest" />
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="../../assets/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5" />
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#603cba" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#007fff" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|PT+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body class="contenedor bg-color">
    <div class="mt-5 pt-5">
        <form action="Controller/registrarEventosCtrl.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-registro" id="formulario-evento">
            <h1>Formulario Eventos</h1>
            <?php if (isset($_SESSION['mensaje'])) { ?>
                <div class="alert alert-<?php echo $_SESSION['mensaje_color']; ?> alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                    <?php echo $_SESSION['mensaje']; ?>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
            <?php session_unset();
            } ?>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="../../assets/img/gallery.svg" class="icono" id="attachment">
                <br>
                <input type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" class="ent" style="margin-bottom: 22rem; display: none; cursor: pointer" id="file-input" name="portada">
                <br><br>
                <!-- La imagen que vamos a usar para previsualizar lo que el usuario selecciona -->
                <img id="imagenPrevisualizacion">
                <script src="../../assets/js/script.js"></script>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <label for="">Título</label>
                <input type="text" name="titulo_event" id="titulo_event" class="ent" placeholder="Ingrese título">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <label for="">Descripción</label>
                <textarea name="descripcion_event" id="descripcion_event" cols="30" rows="10" class="ent txt-area text-dark"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <label>Fecha</label>
                <input type="date" class="ent" name="fecha_event">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <label>Hora</label>
                <input type="time" class="ent" name="hora_event">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <label>Cupo</label>
                <input type="number" class="ent" name="cupo_event">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <label>Activo</label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="ent" name="check_activo" style="margin-left: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;margin-bottom: 0rem;left: -599px;">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <label>Tarifa</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1" style="padding-bottom: 0px;padding-top: 0px;margin-top: 1px;margin-bottom: 21px; font-size:large">$</span>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="tarifa_event">
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="botn" onclick="document.forms.registro.submit();" name="guardar">Guardar</button>
            </div>
 
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive altura mt-4 mb-5">
        <table class="mt-4 table table-striped table-hover" id="tabla_eventos">
            <thead class="table-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th class="col">#</th>
                    <th class="col">Título</th>
                    <th class="col">Descripción</th>
                    <th class="col">Tarifa</th>
                    <th class="col">Fecha</th>
                    <th class="col">Hora</th>
                    <th class="col">Activo</th>
                    <th class="col">Imagen</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['idEvento']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['Titulo']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['Descripcion']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['Tarifa']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['Fecha']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['Hora']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['Activo']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['linkImg']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="../../assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <p></p>
    
</body>

</html>
```

**Controlador: registrarEventosCtrler.php**

```php
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', '1');     
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');     
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once '../../config/conexionBD.php';
$titulo_evento = $conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['titulo_event']);
$descripcion_evento = $conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['descripcion_event']);
$fecha_evento = $_POST['fecha_event'];
$hora_evento = $_POST['hora_event'];
$cupo_evento = $_POST['cupo_event'];
$tarifa_evento = $_POST['tarifa_event'];
$id = $_SESSION['id_user'];

if(isset($_POST['check_activo'])){
        $check_activo = 1;
}else{
        $check_activo = 0;
}



if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){

//  if(!empty($_POST['titulo_event']) || !empty($_POST['descripcion_event']) || !empty($_POST['fecha_event']) || !empty($_POST['hora_event']) || !empty($_POST['cupo_event']) || !empty($_POST['tarifa_event'])){
 if(!empty($_POST['titulo_event']) || !empty($_POST['descripcion_event']) || !empty($_POST['fecha_event']) || !empty($_POST['hora_event']) || !empty($_POST['cupo_event']) || !empty($_POST['tarifa_event'])){
        $cargarEvento = "INSERT INTO eventos(Titulo, Descripcion, Tarifa, Fecha, Hora, Activo, idOrg)
        VALUES('$titulo_evento', '$descripcion_evento', $tarifa_evento, '$fecha_evento','$hora_evento', $check_activo, $id)";
        $agregarEvento = $conexion-> query($cargarEvento);
        $id = $conexion->insert_id;
        // if($_FILES['portada']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
        //         $permitidos = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png");
        //         $tamanio = $_FILES['portada']['size'];
        //         if(in_array($_FILES['portada']['type'], $permitidos)){
        //                 $portada = fopen($_FILES['portada']['tmp_name'],'r');
        //                 $portada_evento = fread($portada,$tamanio);

        //                 $cargarEvento = "INSERT INTO eventos(linkImg)
        //                 VALUES('$portada_evento') WHERE idEvento = $id";
        //                 $agregarEvento = $conexion-> query($cargarEvento);
               
        //         }else{
        //                 $_SESSION['mensaje'] .= "<br>Formato de imágen no permitido";
        //                 $_SESSION['mensaje_color'] = 'danger';
        //         }
        // }else{
        //         $_SESSION['mensaje'] = "Error al guardar imagen";
        //         $_SESSION['mensaje_color'] = 'danger';
        //         header('Location: ../formulario_eventos.php');
        // } 
        }else{
                $_SESSION['mensaje'] .= 'Rellene todos los campos';
                $_SESSION['mensaje_color'] = 'alert';
        }
        header("Location: ../formulario_eventos.php");
}
```

**Conexión con base de datos**

```php
<?php 
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$base_name = "taquillanet";

try {
    $conexion = new mysqli("localhost",$user, $password, $base_name);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    printf("Fallo la conexión".$e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

*Pd: Lo comentado es para guardar la imágen en la base de datos, cosa que tampoco he logrado hacer en otros proyectos.
Uso VSCode y Xammp como servidor MySql y PHP

Comment: Revisa el log de errores, hay varias cosas que necesitarías mejorar. Por ejemplo, `real_escape_string` tiene un pasado oscuro en cuanto a seguridad, en el caso de consultas a la base de datos, deberías usar mejor consultas preparadas. Luego, no veo que estés activando el modo de reporte de errores de mysqli, por lo que el `try ... catch` no funcionará en la parte de la conexión. Si por ahora no sabes dónde encontrar el log de errores, pon esto temporalmente al inicio de tus scripts PHP: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices de la seguridad, en cuanto a el log de errores no está en xammp y coloqué el código que me recomendaste en el controlador del formulario y sigue sin aparecer errores en la consola del navegador. En definitiva sigo igual

Comment: De momento, pon `ini_set('display_errors', '1');  ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');  error_reporting(E_ALL);` al inicio de todos los archivos `.php` que intervienen aquí, para poder saber con certeza qué falla y dónde falla.

Comment: Encontré un log con los siguientes warnings:
 PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): (42000/1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2 in D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\TaquillaNET\\app\\Eventos\\Controller\\registrarEventosCtrl.php on line 24, referer: http://localhost/TaquillaNET/app/Eventos/formulario_eventos.php

Comment: Y este otro:
[Thu May 18 20:28:12.015932 2023] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $_SESSION in D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\TaquillaNET\\app\\Eventos\\Controller\\registrarEventosCtrl.php on line 12, referer: http://localhost/TaquillaNET/app/Eventos/formulario_eventos.php

Comment: Ves, el log de errores es oro molido, debes revisarlo siempre que un código no funcione, te va a ahorrar muuuuchos dolores de cabeza y muuuchos días rompiéndote el coco tratando de adivinar qué es lo que falla. Ahí dice claramente que tienes problemas en el archivo `registrarEventosCtrl.php`, revisa lo que ocurre en las líneas `2` y `12` de dicho archivo. Si no encuentras la solución, agrega el código de ese archivo a la pregunta para que lo revisemos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logré solucionarlo, muchas gracias por lo de la sugerencia activar los errores del log, resulta que el inconveniente estaba en que había escrito mal el nombre de la variable que contenía el id del usuario que lo había almacenado en sesión al ser nulo ese parámetro que estaba dentro de la consulta de inserción a la base de datos me daba un error de sintaxis. Muchas gracias A. Cedano por la ayuda